# Manipulating both unicode and ASCII character set in C#

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I have this mapping in my C# application

`string [,] unicode2Ascii = {
{ "&#3001;", "\x86" }
};`

ஹ - is the unicode value for a tamil literal "ஹ". This is the raw hex literal for the unicode value saved by MS Word as a byte sequence. I am trying to map these unicode value "strings" to a hex value under 255 (so as to accommodate non-unicode supported systems).

I trying to use string.replace like this:

```
S = S.replace(unicode2Ascii[0,0], unicode2Ascii[0,1]);
```

However the resultant ouput has a ? instead of the actual hex 0x86 stored. Any pointer on how I could set the encoding for the second element of that array to something like windows-1252?

Or is there a better way to do this conversion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but the Tamil codepage "57004 - ISCII Tamil" is supported by Windows.

It does not give the same translation for the example character above though. For 'ஹ' it gives 216. Perhaps a different codepage needs to be used?

```
        string tamilUnicodeString = "ஹ";

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("x-iscii-ta");

        byte[] codepageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(tamilUnicodeString);
```

**Update**

If you wish to take a unicode file as input, transliterate characters to get a single byte representation, the following should do the trick. The resulting array should have your single byte representation if your dictionary encodes each character:

```
        Dictionary<char, char> lookup = new Dictionary<char, char>
        {
            { 'ஹ', '\x86' },
            { 'இ',  '\x87' },
            //next pair...,
            //etc, etc.
        };

        string input = "ஹஇதில் உள்ள தமிழ் எழுத்துக்கள் சரியாகத் தெரிந்தால்";

        char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            char replaceChar;

            if (lookup.TryGetValue(chars[i], out replaceChar))
            {
                chars[i] = replaceChar;
            }
        }

        byte[] output = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(chars);
```

Comment: The intent wasnt to retrieve the ascii code equivalent for the unicode character. Instead simply replace it with "some" ascii code character defined in that mapping table. Basically I am trying to see how I can represent 0x86 as a string in .NET so that I can employ string.replace method to replace the &#3001 literal

Comment: @Murlex I'm confused as to exactly what result you're expecting when converting a unicode file which is Tamil text, into an ANSI file in codepage 1252 (as described in the question). Who is the intended audience?

Comment: We had a Tamil Codepage standard called TSCII (www.tscii.org) before the UNICODE spec came into being. There are still some systems that arent supporting the new shaping engine required for displaying tamil unicode characters. Hence we sometimes need to "downgrade" unicode text to the 1-byte TSCII standard.

Comment: @Murlex I see - I presume converting to the "x-iscii-ta" code page is no good to you. That is ISCII not TSCII.

Comment: @Murlex Out of interest how do your non-unicode users go about installing and selecting a code page on Windows? How do you install support for TSCII?

Comment: The TSCII.org basically created custom fonts that populate in the non-ascii region (but under 255) all the characters from the Tamil Script. You will need to use those fonts to read the text.

Comment: @Murlex I have updated my answer with a code sample which will allow a dictionary of characters to be replaced in an input string. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks chibacity...that is somewhat similar to what I ended up implementing as well.. it was something like this... new TsciiMapInfo(@"ழௌ" , new byte[] {0xA6,0xC6,0xAA} ); I created a class to handle this map, as some characters are actually multi byte representation. Also Word documents used hex literals for unicode characters like "&#2996;&#3020;" for the character ழௌ. I had to add that to the map as well.. Since yours was close to what I ended up (and also I did get the idea from you to start with)...I've tagged your post as the answer to my question...

Answer (score 3):

Strings in .NET are always Unicode internally. However this does not really matter. Strings are a series in characters and .NET strings supports all unicode characters. You should not care how they are presented in memory. You care about encoding only when your strings leave (or enter) .NET (i.e. when you write (read) them to files, send (receive) them over sockets to other systems, etc.). This is when you use the Encoding class to convert to whatever encoding you desire. Replacing characters or trying any encoding tricks on .NET strings is pointless.
Also I recommend this article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Yes the intent of the excercise is to modify the contents of a file. Thanks for the link. Will read that up as well..

Comment: Then you modify the string and when you write the string to the file you use specific encoding. In .NET code you don't need to use any unicode code points numbers. You can use the symbol directly in the .NET source.

Comment: Thanks for the link again. I got some basic understanding on how encoding is to be used when read from and written to files.